# Running Parallel Android devices in Robot Framework

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework + Appium for  automating Android  Mobile apps and it is working fine with the single physical device connected.

I have scenario to execute the same for multiple devices in parallel. I have googled and found only one useful forum.
http://testnblog.com/executing-robot-test-cases-in-parallel-on-2-android-devices-through-appium/

When I followed the above steps I was able to run the multiple Appium instances but when I call the same from Robot Framework, like mentioned in the forum, I am getting below error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created. (Original error
: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "D:\adb\adt-bundle-windows-x
86_64-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell "getprop persist.sys.language""
error: more than one device/emulator)
```

Can anyone please help me to come out or suggesting the solution if you have achieved the same using Robot framework

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a similar response in your Selenium Grid, `INFO - Registered a node http://0.0.0.0:4723`,  and `INFO - Registered a node http://0.0.0.0:4730`. Note the two different ports.

Comment: Yes I am able see two different nodes

Comment: Have you tried running each node on a different physical machine?

Comment: No .. My requirement is to run it in a single machine

Comment: This would help with the elimination process that running the same application twice causes the issue.